# Amount of fluid that moves along a path

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Let suppose that $\vec{F}$ is the velocity vector field of of a fluid in space, and $\vec{s}$ is a straight path of arbitrary length. Let's suppose that $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{s}$ are parallels and point in the same direction, so that $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{s} = F s$. How can we account for the total amount of fluid that moves along the path (per unit of time).

[**Related question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849581/line-integral-as-circulation-but-why#comment1752006_849611)

Comment: I don't think you can get a non-infinitesimal answer by using a one-dimensional path $\vec s$. Don't you need some type of non-zero cross-sectional area to your path?